# Why are wides are not considered in test matches, but no balls are considered?

Tags: rules, cricket

In cricket, why are wides are not considered in test matches, but no balls are considered?

Answer (score 6):

In test cricket the laws of cricket definition of a wide ball is used. [law 25 wide ball](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-25-wide-ball/).  In that a ball is a wide if it is not possible to play a normal cricket shot from his normal stance.

In ODI and T20 cricket this is modified by an instruction to be very strict on wides, if the batsment can not play a scoring shot it shall be called wide.  They also place guidance marks on the pitch to help judge wides.  Also generally deliveries down the legside will be wided.

Answer (score 2):

Wides *are* considered in test matches (and all other cricket) - however, the criteria for a wide in first class cricket and much looser than in one-day cricket; principally the ball has to be *much* wider than it does in one-day cricket.

For a famous example, see Steve Harmison's [first ball of the 2006/7 Ashes series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7Y6T44tzIc).